# Сортировка options внутри select

Tags: javascript

Есть несколько списков в HTML:

```
<select data-temp_number="144" data-key="pa_razmer-struny" data-label="Размер струны" class="filter_select select2 filter filter_select_pa_razmer-struny" id="pa_razmer-struny_144"><option value="">Размер струны</option><option value="pa_razmer-struny_144_488">20 мм</option><option value="pa_razmer-struny_144_489">25 мм</option><option value="pa_razmer-struny_144_490">30 мм</option><option value="pa_razmer-struny_144_491">21 мм</option><option value="pa_razmer-struny_144_492">5 мм</option><option value="pa_razmer-struny_144_493">35 мм</option></select><br>
<select data-temp_number="144" data-key="pa_dlina" data-label="Длина" class="filter_select select2 filter filter_select_pa_dlina" id="pa_dlina_144"><option value="">Длина</option><option value="pa_dlina_144_152">1700 мм</option><option value="pa_dlina_144_242">2100 мм</option><option value="pa_dlina_144_358">1950 мм</option></select>
```

И есть код на JS, который призван сделать сортировку

```
function sorted(names){
for(var c=document.getElementsByClassName(names)[0],b=c.options,a=0;a<b.length;)
    if( b[a+1] && parseFloat(b[a].text) > parseFloat(b[a+1].text) ){
        c.insertBefore(b[a+1],b[a]);
        a = a >= 1 ? a-1 : a+1
    } else a++;
    b[0].selected=true 
};

sorted("filter_select");
```

Проблема в том, что этот код, почему-то, делает сортировку только для первого списка, второй будто не видит. В чем моя ошибка? Ведь у обоих списков одинаковый class и я а JS получает элемент по getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 1):

Лично мне ваш код читать было трудно(a,b,c...), вот простой пример как можно отсортировать `options`:

```js
function sort(names) {
  const selects = document.getElementsByClassName(names)

  for (let i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
    const currentSelect = selects[i],
      sortedOptions = [...currentSelect.options].sort((o1, o2) => parseFloat(o1.text) - parseFloat(o2.text))

    currentSelect.innerHTML = ''
    sortedOptions.forEach(o => currentSelect.add(o))

    currentSelect.selectedIndex = 0
  }
};

sort("filter_select");
```

```html
<select data-temp_number="144" data-key="pa_razmer-struny" data-label="Размер струны" class="filter_select select2 filter filter_select_pa_razmer-struny" id="pa_razmer-struny_144">
  <option value="">Размер струны</option>
  <option value="pa_razmer-struny_144_488">20 мм</option>
  <option value="pa_razmer-struny_144_489">25 мм</option>
  <option value="pa_razmer-struny_144_490">30 мм</option>
  <option value="pa_razmer-struny_144_491">21 мм</option>
  <option value="pa_razmer-struny_144_492">5 мм</option>
  <option value="pa_razmer-struny_144_493">35 мм</option>
</select><br>
<select data-temp_number="144" data-key="pa_dlina" data-label="Длина" class="filter_select select2 filter filter_select_pa_dlina" id="pa_dlina_144">
  <option value="">Длина</option>
  <option value="pa_dlina_144_152">1700 мм</option>
  <option value="pa_dlina_144_242">2100 мм</option>
  <option value="pa_dlina_144_358">1950 мм</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы, видимо, плохо представляете, как работает цикл for

```
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) { // выведет 0, затем 1, затем 2
  alert(i);
}
```

i = 0   Выполняется один раз при входе в цикл

Так же и у вас

```
var c=document.getElementsByClassName(names)[0],b=c.options,a=0
```

выполнится ОДИН раз при инициализации цикла. 
Поэтому и select отсортируется только  первый.

Инициализацию переменных, которые отвечают за свойства селектов, нужно перенести внутрь цикла.

И еще момент

```
var c=document.getElementsByClassName(names)[0]
```

Здесь вы всегда обращаетесь к первому элементу выборки, к первому селекту.